# Android APK signatures V1 and V2 conflict

Tags: android, apk, signing

APK with V1 signature already at Google Play and installed on devices lover **Android** **11**.
Now we want to support Android 11 devices, but it requires V2 signature.
Enabling the check-boxes of both V1 and V2 we get APK, but it refuses to be installed with INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE.

How possible to build APK which will be supported by all devices?

I checked signature certificates of built APKs. They are Release certificates.

***Some probably useful logs snippet:***

```
2021-05-31 23:20:41.525 23694-27663/? I/Finsky: [6921] VerifyPerSourceInstallationConsentInstallTask.mJ(2): PSIC verification started with installer uid: 2000 package name: null, originating uid: -1
2021-05-31 23:20:41.527 23694-23694/? I/Finsky: [2] VerifyInstallTask.j(3): Verifying id=30, result=1
2021-05-31 23:20:41.528 1129-5146/? D/PackageManager: [VERIFY] verifyPendingInstall(30, ALLOW), uid=10072
2021-05-31 23:20:41.528 1129-1571/? D/PackageManager: [VERIFY] PACKAGE_VERIFIED: 
    PackageVerificationState{
        verifier packages=com.android.vending(10072),
        intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_NEEDS_VERIFICATION dat=file:///data/app/vmdl129480116.tmp typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x10000001 cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.verifier.impl.PackageVerificationReceiver (has extras) }
        others=30, false, false, false, false, false
    }
2021-05-31 23:20:41.529 1129-1571/? D/PackageManager: [VERIFY] setVerifierResponse {verificationID=30, uid=10072, code=1}
2021-05-31 23:20:41.529 1129-1571/? D/PackageManager: [VERIFY] packageVerificationCompletion: completed id=30
2021-05-31 23:20:41.529 23694-23694/? I/Finsky: [2] VerifyInstallTask.mI(6): Verification complete: id=30, package_name=com.our.app
2021-05-31 23:20:41.550 1129-1571/? W/PackageManager: verifying app can be installed or not
2021-05-31 23:20:41.551 1129-1571/? D/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationInstallationEnabled
2021-05-31 23:20:41.551 1129-1571/? D/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationInstallationEnabled :  Checking PKG WL - false
2021-05-31 23:20:41.551 1129-1571/? D/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationInstallationEnabled :  Checking PKG BL - true
2021-05-31 23:20:41.551 1129-1571/? D/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationInstallationEnabled :  Checking PERM BL - true
2021-05-31 23:20:41.551 1129-1571/? D/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationInstallationEnabled :  Checking SIG BL - true
2021-05-31 23:20:41.551 1129-1571/? D/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationInstallationEnabled :  Checking PKG WL - false
2021-05-31 23:20:41.551 1129-1571/? D/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationInstallationEnabled :  Checking PKG BL - true
2021-05-31 23:20:41.551 1129-1571/? D/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationInstallationEnabled :  Checking PERM BL - true
2021-05-31 23:20:41.551 1129-1571/? D/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationInstallationEnabled :  Checking SIG BL - true
2021-05-31 23:20:41.552 1129-1571/? D/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationInstallationEnabled :  Checking PKG WL - false
2021-05-31 23:20:41.552 1129-1571/? D/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationInstallationEnabled :  Checking PKG BL - true
2021-05-31 23:20:41.552 1129-1571/? D/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationInstallationEnabled :  Checking PERM BL - true
2021-05-31 23:20:41.552 1129-1571/? D/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationInstallationEnabled :  Checking SIG BL - true
2021-05-31 23:20:41.552 1129-1571/? D/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationInstallationEnabled :  Checking PKG WL - false
2021-05-31 23:20:41.552 1129-1571/? D/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationInstallationEnabled :  Checking PKG BL - true
2021-05-31 23:20:41.552 1129-1571/? D/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationInstallationEnabled :  Checking PERM BL - true
2021-05-31 23:20:41.552 1129-1571/? D/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationInstallationEnabled :  Checking SIG BL - true
2021-05-31 23:20:41.552 1129-1571/? D/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationInstallationEnabled :  enabled true
2021-05-31 23:20:41.552 1129-1571/? W/PackageManager: Package com.our.app signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!
2021-05-31 23:20:41.571 1129-1571/? D/PackageManager: result of install: -7{216565249}
2021-05-31 23:20:41.572 1143-28449/? E/installd: Couldn't opendir /data/app/vmdl129480116.tmp: No such file or directory
2021-05-31 23:20:41.572 1143-28449/? E/installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl129480116.tmp: No such file or directory
2021-05-31 23:20:41.574 1129-4377/? D/PackageInstallerSession: Ignoring abandon after commit relinquished control
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue does not seem to be with v1 and v2 signatures but with the keystore you're using to sign your app.

The error message `Package com.our.app signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!` indicates that the app that is currently installed on the device was not signed with the same key as the one you're trying to install.

Are you by any chance enrolled in Play App Signing (you can check that in the "App integrity" page of the Play Console)? If so, you may have a version of your app signed by Google's app signing key installed, and you're trying to install a version of your app signed with your upload key (which in Studio would be called the "release key").

If you uninstall the app and reinstall it with the v1+v2 signed APK, it should install properly.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Google did signing with its key. You absolutely correct.